# VBA Import Dynamic URL

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to auto import text files into Excel and am having a bit of an issue.

I am using banana as the dynamic equation here with the URL, but am failing.

http://regsho.finra.org/regsho-September.html

```
Option Explicit 

Public Sub testing()
   Dim qt As QueryTable
   Dim ws As Worksheet
   Dim banana As String

   Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
   
   banana = Range("C4").Value
    
   Const URL As String = "http://regsho.finra.org/CNMSshvo"" & banana & "".txt"

   Set qt = ws.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;" & URL, Destination:=ws.Range("A1"))

   With qt
      .RefreshOnFileOpen = True
      .FieldNames = True
      .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
      .WebTables = 1
      .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
   End With 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you add the `banana` variable the wrong way to the text string.  You're doing:

```
Const URL As String = "http://regsho.finra.org/CNMSshvo"" & banana & "".txt"
```

while this should be

```
Const URL As String = "http://regsho.finra.org/CNMSshvo" & banana & ".txt"
```

i.e. replace the doubled double quotes by a single double quote.  Having 2 double quotes in a string will insert a single textual double quote in the text (it's called escaping), which means the string just continues after the inserted double quote.  Which in turn means you have the literal text "banana" (incl. quotes) in your string.  So you end up with the following URL:

```
http://regsho.finra.org/CNMSshvo" & banana & ".txt
```

One way to hunt these sort of things out is by adding the following after your const string:

```
call MsgBox(URL)
```

and you'll soon find out what URL you have built :)